# Why doesn't this memcpy work?

Tags: c++, memcpy

So I have the following code, a simplified version of what I want to do. I have a class with a member variable that I want to set to potentially a variety of different data types, depending on the situation (i just made a random struct for this test). I keep getting seg faults on the memcpy function though, and I have no idea why.

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <assert.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 using namespace std;

struct product
{
        int price;
        string name;
};


class object
{
public:
        void setData(void *ptr);
        void* data;
};


void object::setData(void *ptr)
{
        assert(ptr);
        memcpy(data, ptr, sizeof(ptr));
}


int main()
{
        product* bag;
        product ba;
        bag = &ba;
        bag->price = 5;
        bag->name = "bag";

        object test;
        test.setData(bag);

        cout<<test.data->name<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(ptr)`???? What do you expect this to be?

Comment: Also - you can't just `memcpy` a string object.

Comment: And even if you got the `sizeof` correct, you cannot use `memcpy` on non-POD types, such as your `product` class.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has multiple issues, but a direct cause of SIGSEGV is following line:
`memcpy(data, ptr, sizeof(ptr));` which tries to copy a number of bytes into unallocated pointer `data`.

On a side note, it looks like you are trying to achieve polymorphism in C++ using completely inapproriate methods.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned that the `memcpy` is not correct due to using `sizeof(void*)` as the number of bytes to copy. But changing the `sizeof` to an appropriate value will just have you hit the next stumbling block with using `memcpy`.  You would probably encounter it as soon as you execute this line:

```
cout<<test.data->name<<endl
```

The reason is that `data->name` is more than likely corrupted, invalid, or if you did actually see a name printed, the string is in an unstable state.

Basically, using `memcpy` to set a struct to a certain value isn't going to work if the struct is not a **POD** type.

[What is a POD type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

[POD updates for C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821)

Your `product` class has a member that is a non-POD type, namely `std::string`.  You cannot simply overlay a `std::string` object with bytes of data from another `std::string` object (which is what that `memcpy` will be doing).

The same thing can be said for functions such as `memset` or any `C` oriented function that sets the bytes of what is pointed to with values.  They cannot be used on non-POD types.

Unlike POD types, just doing a copy of bytes like that will corrupt the destination object.  If that object contained, say a v-table, then you really would be ripping the destination object to shreds.

For non-POD types, use the proper C++ techniques, which include using assignment (`data = ptr`).

Comment: As funny as it is, `std::string` is **almost** POD. The only thing which prevents it from being POD is different access control, but this is unlikely to cause any problems with `memcpy`.

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote for referring to outdated POD definition.

Comment: Having a non-trivial destructor also prevents a `std::string` from being "almost POD".

Comment: Not at all, not any more.

Answer (score 0):

Also I suppose it could be problem here

```
 cout<<test.data->name<<endl;
```

case data is void pointer so you need cast here

```
 cout<<static_cast<product *>(test.data)->name<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I don't like any of the answers, so for future readers.

When you cast an object to a void*, you loss the type information associated with it.  That is why you can't use sizeof with a void* ptr.  (This is probably also why memcpy doesn't do it this way).  I think what you need here is to write a Template class.  Then the code will know the type and the code should work.

```
template<class T>
class object
{
public:
        void setData(T *ptr);
        T* data;
};


void object::setData(T *ptr)
{
        assert(ptr);
        memcpy(data, ptr, sizeof(ptr));
}
```